# Getting undefined error from postgresql query in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to execute query and use some rows of the results.

When I tried this code:

```
const pg = require('pg')
var Log = require('fancy-log');
var jsonPath = require('jsonpath');
var validator = require('validator');
var isEmpty = require('is-empty-array')
const argv = require('yargs').argv
require('custom-env').env(argv.env)

var db = require('./db');
var checker = require('./checklist')

let txn_id;
var param = []

//////////////////////////////////// DB Connection Block & executeQuery ////////////////////////////////////

var config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB,
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
}

const pool = new pg.Pool(config)

async function query(q,param) {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    let res
    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN')
        try {
            res = await client.query(q, param)
            await client.query('COMMIT')
            Log("Connection succeed.")
        } catch (err) {
            await client.query('ROLLBACK')
            throw err
        }
    } finally {
        client.release()
    }
    return res
}

//////////////////////////////////// DB Connection Block & executeQuery ////////////////////////////////////


//client.getConnection();

//db.main()
//db.print()

async function executeQuery(queryParam, conditions) {
    try {
        const { rows, rowCount } = await query(queryParam, conditions)
        txn_id = await rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)].txn_id
        Log("Related txn_id: " + txn_id)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Database ' + err)
    }
}


executeQuery("SELECT * from table_name",[])
```

I got this error all the time:

```
Database TypeError: Cannot read property 'txn_id' of undefined
```

My first usecase is working two different js file like `db.js` for connection and `query function`, export it and use it in `main.js`. Unfortunately, I couldn't get success. Probably, I don't understand fully of `await` usage.

Thanks for any idea in advance!

EDIT: This is main goal. I want to seperate all my logics.

**db.js**

```
const pg = require('pg')
var Log = require('fancy-log');
const argv = require('yargs').argv
require('custom-env').env(argv.env)

//var db = function(){};
let txn_id;
var param = []

var config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB,
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
}

const pool = new pg.Pool(config)

async function query(q,param) {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    let res
    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN')
        try {
            res = await client.query(q, param)
            await client.query('COMMIT')
            Log("Connection succeed.")
        } catch (err) {
            await client.query('ROLLBACK')
            throw err
        }
    } finally {
        client.release()
    }
    return res
}

async function executeQuery(queryParam, conditions) {
    try {
        const { rows, rowCount } = await query(queryParam,conditions)
        txn_id = await rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)].txn_id
        Log("Related txn_id: " + txn_id)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Database ' + err)
    }
}


module.exports = {
    executeQuery
}
```

**main.js**

```
const pg = require('pg')
var Log = require('fancy-log');
var jsonPath = require('jsonpath');
var validator = require('validator');
var isEmpty = require('is-empty-array')
const argv = require('yargs').argv
require('custom-env').env(argv.env)

var db = require('./db');
var checker = require('./checklist')



async function foo(){
    await db.executeQuery("SELECT * from table_name",[])
}

foo()
```

Also same error here:

```
Database TypeError: Cannot read property 'txn_id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this already, but since there are no answers, in case someone needs help with this in the future.

**TL;DR:** You have to remove `+1` from `txn_id = await rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)].txn_id`.

`rows` is an array of length N (N rows found in `table_name`) with indices from 0 to N-1, and `rowCount` equals (in this case) `rows.length`; and since:

1) 0 <= `Math.random()` < 1
2) 0 <= `Math.random() * rowCount` < N
3) 1 <= `Math.random() * rowCount + 1` < N+1
4) 1 <= `Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)` < N+1 (only natural numbers now)

then `Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)` produces indeces from 1 to N, which is why sometimes (in case of N) `rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount + 1)]` equals `undefined`.

Also, `await` is not needed here: `await rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount)]`; you already *awaited* for the query to finish here `const { rows, rowCount } = await query(queryParam,conditions)`.

Only place `await` in front of an expression which returns a Promise, otherwise it's doing nothing. ([suggested](https://javascript.info/async-await))